# Is there a way to get the python program to "refresh the sd drive connection"

Tags: python, file, sd-card

My daughters SD card has gone corrupt, and I'm trying to recover the photos/files. I have tried various recover software but to no avail.

However I have found that if I use MSDOS, I can copy various photos, however intermittently this fails and says "theres no disk in drive" 
I assuming the file its trying to copy is corrupt, I can overcome this by pulling out the sd card and re-inserting it.

So opportunity for a program! :) - I got the file names via dos, created a text file and knocked up a rough program.... However I keep getting the "theres no disk in drive"

Hence... Is there a way to get the python program to "refresh the sd drive connection"

Many thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
""" File copy program"""

import os
import shutil

def main(): 
    Basepathfile = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    FileName = 'Filenames.txt'
    PrelimPathFile = os.path.join(Basepathfile, FileName )
    PathFile = os.path.normpath(PrelimPathFile)

    Filename1 = open(PathFile, 'r')
    Filename2 = 'c:\\Lili\\'
    for line in Filename1:
        line = line.replace('\r\n', '').replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '')
        Filename1 = 'f:\\DCIM\\Camera\\'+ line
        Filename2 = 'c:\\Lili\\'+ line

        try:
            shutil.copy2(Filename1, Filename2)
            print 'Copied... '
            print Filename1, '...to...', Filename2
        except:
            print 'Failed to copy ', Filename1, ' to ', Filename2

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds more like a question about Windows than Python. If your SD card is plugged in via a USB card reader, the easiest approach would probably be to disable and re-enable the USB hub device it is connected to. This will cause windows to re-enumerate all the USB devices attached to that hub.

You can do this from the command line with `DevCon`: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272

If this is something other than a USB device, I'm not really sure, but maybe DevCon can still do the trick by trying to disable and re-enable the device directly.

Alternatively you could try doing it manually with `robocopy`. It has options not to copy the files it has already copied. You'd still have to manually pull the SD card a few times, but if you're lucky, the SD card will stay up long enough to confirm everything was pulled across eventually.

Comment: Cheers Hetman, in the end I just ran the program, repeatedly removing installing the drive. Took about 80 re-inserts, and lost about 80 items, but thats better then all. I full format, heavy test of the SD and had no problems since